# Setting up a github.com repository in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I couldn't find a concise step-by-step tutorial to integrate Visual Studio Code with github.com and I'm struggling with this.

This is what I did:

- I installed Visual Studio Code (VSC)
- Within VSC I installed two extensions: GitHub 0.30.3 and GitHub Pull Requests 0.13.0
- I tried to configure the github.com remote site in VSC, all I could find [here](https://github.com/chuong9x/Extention-for-Visual-Studio-Code/blob/master/github.vscode-pull-request-github-0.11.2/package.json) is that there's a `githubPullRequests.hosts` entry, but no place to put a user/password.

Can the complete setup happen inside VSC or there's something that needs to be done with a `git` command? How to make VSC aware of a repository in github.com ?

Comment: Visual Studio Code will allow you to handle git repos out of the box, without extensions. What sort of integration do you want?

Comment: This article seems to have a lot of information: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/09/10/introducing-github-pullrequests

Comment: @oyvind Thanks for the article, but it doesn't talk about configuration, specifically how to set gitbub's user and password in VSC.

Comment: This video has the answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cMWR-EGFuY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.  From [add remote repository from github (v1.46 release notes)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#add-remote-from-github):

> You can now easily add a GitHub repository as a remote to your local repositories using the `Git: Add Remote...` command.

[image: add remote github repository]